# Build URL path while recursively searching a hierarchical array for an id

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, parent-child

I have a multidimensional array and I want to build an url providing only the id of the children.

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'id' => '1',
    'p_pag' => '0',
    'link' => 'Contact',
    'children' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'id' => '2',
        'p_pag' => '1',
        'link' => 'Contact-County',
        'children' => 
        array (
          0 => 
          array (
            'id' => '3',
            'p_pag' => '2',
            'link' => 'Contact-Town-1',
            'children' => 
            array (
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I expect a function where to specify the array above and the `id` as `3` in order to obtain an link like this `/Contact/Contact-County/Contact-Town-1/`

My attempt:

```
function getlink($array,$id)
{
    $link='';
    foreach($array as $aindex => $aval)
    {
        if($aval['id']==$id){$link.='/'.$aval['link'];}
        elseif($aval['children']){...}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive approach where you traverse all children subarrays in search of the targeted id.  When an id is found, start building the string as you return back up the branch until you hit the top level.  When there are no parents to return to, the built string will be returned from the function.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qH3bu))

```
function getLinkPathById(array $array, string $toId): ?string
{
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        if (
            ($deeper = getLinkPathById($row['children'], $toId))
            || $row['id'] === $toId
        ) {
            return "/{$row['link']}$deeper";
        }
    }
    return null;
}

echo "1: " . getLinkPathById($array, 1) . PHP_EOL;
echo "2: " . getLinkPathById($array, 2) . PHP_EOL;
echo "3: " . getLinkPathById($array, 3) . PHP_EOL;
echo "4: " . getLinkPathById($array, 4);
```

Output from 4 different tests:

```
1: /Contact
2: /Contact/Contact-County
3: /Contact/Contact-County/Contact-Town-1
4:
```